# Ajax call from localhost or using full URL to live server not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a webpage on live server. Suppose 'www.mydomain.com/server_script/test.php' this one. Now I'm making a AJAX call from localhost like

```
var data={
                    type:'data1'                           

                };

                jQuery.ajax({
                          url: 'http://www.mydomain.com/server_script/test.php',  //load data 
                          global: false,
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "xml",
                          data: data,
                          async: false, 
                          success: loading_complete
                });
```

**It supposed to provide me a XML structure.** But it's not working. It doesn't provide anything also not showing any error.

When I'm working with all local files, it's working properly. like

```
var data={
                    type:'data1'                           

                };

                jQuery.ajax({
                          url: 'server_script/test.php',  //load data 
                          global: false,
                          type: "POST",
                          dataType: "xml",
                          data: data,
                          async: false, 
                          success: loading_complete
                });
```

But I need to retrieve data from web server. **This is required because I need to fetch data from one site and collect it from another.**

I've also tried to put the calling page in live server and call the file as 1st code sample, it didn't work either. It only works as with the 2nd code sample.

I'm novice to Jquery Ajax and php. Am I missing something? How can I make a call to a page that is hosted on a different domain and get the response in XML?? Please help.........

Comment: can you post the PHP code which returns the data as well?

Comment: for a cross domain request add this header in your php  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.

Comment: I can assure you that they are fully functional.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your server script allow being requested from any or specific origin by setting correct headers.

add this in your server script.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

This error occurs because of cross domain request restrictions set by your browser for security reasons. A temporary solution is to launch your browser with no security flags but that is kind of low level solution, programming solution is to set proper headers in your php script. In `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` you can either specify a client address if your client address is fixed or use * to allow access from anywhere. In case of `*` you might wanna send an additional parameter to server from client so the server can restrict response to some level. There might be other solutions and alternatives where you can avoid using '*' for no fix client. Kindly do share any alternative solutions if somebody got one.

Comment: launch chrome with --disable-web-security and then check your code

Comment: Also keep an eye on your requests in chrome developer tools -> network tab to check out what's going on.